# How do set size of state After moved child state using AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, air, flash

In my air project i used current state size is width="441" height="358"  . i have link button like Singin then move to singin state (currentstate='singin')

```
 <mx:State name="signin">
         <mx:SetProperty name="height" value="616"/>
         <mx:SetProperty name="width" value="919"/>
```

So application resize into 616,919 . After that function finished move to current state like(currentstate='') But size not be changed . How can i set the size for current state?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of an `<mx>` tag for you to use, if there is one. If you can get a reference to the [NativeWindow](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/NativeWindow.html), you can set it's size with the width/height using actionscript.